# Azure Functions Python - cant install packages

Tags: python, azure, pip, azure-functions

I have Azure Functions which uses pygrib, and pygrib needs numpy and pyproj. So i placed all of them in "requirements.txt". When i deploy my function, an error pops up called: `Cant import pygrib, no module named: pygrib` But I included it earlier in "requirements". How can i solve this?

Comment: I suspect there were a lot of errors installing pygrib. First, numpy and pyproj are required to be already installed when you install pygrib so you cannot put them into one `requirements.txt`. Second, you need GRIB API. See https://jswhit.github.io/pygrib/docs/index.html

Comment: But how can i install it manually on Azure Functions? I dont have any console to get access to this vm. I can only deploy it via Visual Studio